# Can't compile luatex on windows 10 terminal

Tags: pdftex, luatex, windows, terminal-output

I'm trying to compile some TeX files through a windows `.bat` script to avoid having to open them all on TeXWorks.

Compilation runs just fine on TeXWorks but when I'm runing `luatex file.tex`on the `cmd` terminal, it outputs a pdf containing part of the `.log` file as it seems.

---

**Context :**

- Running on windows 10 with MikTeX up to date (I'm more used to linux terminal but I had to get back to windows to be able to use some softwares).
- I use LuaLaTeX to parse a csv file inside of LaTeX
- File tree is the following, where `0_commands.tex` contains my `\newcommand` statements and `automatisation.tex` contains the luacode (both of them are `\input` inside of the main `.tex` file). `Graphismes` is a folder containing pdf backgrounds.

```
0_commands.tex
automatisation.tex
carte_menu.aux
carte_menu.log
carte_menu.pdf
carte_menu.tex
colour_profiles.tex
Graphismes
```

---

Here is the command prompt result. I don't understand why TeXWorks is running just fine while compiling through window's terminal is going wrong...

```
C:\Users\etien\Documents\Entreprise_2020\Abonnements\Epicurien_prototypage\tex>luatex carte_menu.tex
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.12.0 (MiKTeX 20.6.29)
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./carte_menu.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.23 \documentclass
                 {article}
! Undefined control sequence.
l.26 \usepackage
              [T1]{fontenc}
! Undefined control sequence.
l.27 \usepackage
              [french]{babel}
! Undefined control sequence.
l.29 \usepackage
              {newunicodechar}
! Undefined control sequence.
l.30 \newunicodechar
                  {€}{\texteuro}
! Undefined control sequence.
l.30 \newunicodechar{€}{\texteuro
                                 }
! Undefined control sequence.
l.49 \usepackage
              [paperwidth=43cm,paperheight=30.7cm,total={41cm, 28.7cm}]{geom...

! Undefined control sequence.
l.53 \usepackage
              {eso-pic,graphicx}
! Undefined control sequence.
l.54 \graphicspath
                {{./Graphismes/}}%dossier des graphismes
! Undefined control sequence.
l.64 \newcommand
              {\ColG}{97mm}%largeur colonne gauche
! Undefined control sequence.
l.64 \newcommand{\ColG
                    }{97mm}%largeur colonne gauche
! Undefined control sequence.
l.65 \newcommand
              {\ColM}{194mm}%largeur colonne milieu
! Undefined control sequence.
l.65 \newcommand{\ColM
                    }{194mm}%largeur colonne milieu
! Undefined control sequence.
l.66 \newcommand
              {\ColD}{97mm}%largeur colonne droite
! Undefined control sequence.
l.66 \newcommand{\ColD
                    }{97mm}%largeur colonne droite
! Undefined control sequence.
l.67 \newcommand
              {\ColH}{260mm}%hauteur toutes colonnes
! Undefined control sequence.
l.67 \newcommand{\ColH
                    }{260mm}%hauteur toutes colonnes
! Undefined control sequence.
l.68 \newcommand
              {\Gap}{1cm}
! Undefined control sequence.
l.68 \newcommand{\Gap
                   }{1cm}
! Undefined control sequence.
l.69 \setlength
             \parindent{0pt}
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
{
l.69 \setlength\parindent{
                        0pt}
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again>
{
l.69 \setlength\parindent{
                        0pt}
! Undefined control sequence.
l.79 \title
         {}
! Undefined control sequence.
l.80 \author
          {}
! Undefined control sequence.
l.81 \date
        {}
! Undefined control sequence.
l.91 \usepackage
              {luacode}
(./automatisation.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.5 \usepackage
             {stringstrings}
! Undefined control sequence.
l.6 \usepackage
             {ifthen}
! Undefined control sequence.
l.8 \usepackage
             {expl3}%répétition des commandes > utilisé pour définir com...

! Undefined control sequence.
l.9     \ExplSyntaxOn

! Undefined control sequence.
l.10     \cs
          _new_eq:NN \Repeat \prg_replicate:nn% Crée la commande \Repeat{<n...

! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
$
<to be read again>
_
l.10     \cs_
           new_eq:NN \Repeat \prg_replicate:nn% Crée la commande \Repeat{<n...

! Undefined control sequence.
l.10     \cs_new_eq:NN \Repeat
                             \prg_replicate:nn% Crée la commande \Repeat{<n...

! Undefined control sequence.
l.10     \cs_new_eq:NN \Repeat \prg
                                 _replicate:nn% Crée la commande \Repeat{<n...

! Undefined control sequence.
l.11     \ExplSyntaxOff

! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
$
<to be read again>
\par
l.12

! Undefined control sequence.
l.17 \begin
         {luacode*} -- CVS API: http://nocurve.com/simple-csv-read-and-write...

! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
$
<to be read again>
^
l.20      local matchfunc = string.gmatch(str, "([^
                                                 "..sep.."]+)")
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
$
<to be read again>
\par
l.27


Overfull \hbox (233.88812pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 17--27
\tenrm fields= lo-cal match-func = string.gmatch(str, "([$[][]\teni ::sep::\ten
rm "]+)")\teni ifnotmatchfuncthenreturn[]endforstrinmatchfuncdotable:insert\ten
rm (\teni fields; str\tenrm )\teni endreturnfieldsend$ |
! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode.
l.36             for i=1,#
                        fields do
[1{C:/Users/etien/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]))
(see the transcript file for additional information)<C:/Users/etien/AppData/Loc
al/Programs/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi10.pfb><C:/Users/etien/Ap
pData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi7.pfb><C:/Users/
etien/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb><C
:/Users/etien/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr7
.pfb>
Output written on carte_menu.pdf (1 page, 50393 bytes).
Transcript written on carte_menu.log.
```

Comment: you should run lualatex, not luatex.

Comment: The error is as Ulrike says but `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` is almost certainly wrong for luatex, that is using legacy 8bit encodings designed for pdftex, it is best tu use teh default Unicode encoding with lualatex and xelatex.

Comment: Hahah, runing lualatex worked ... i feel so bad X-D